# Eclipse CDT exceeding 32k CreateProcess limit during build on Windows

Tags: windows, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I've ran into a problem during the C/C++ build using Eclipse/CDT for a project containing many source files - during the linking phase a very long command line is created that is then passed to CreateProcess Windows API function. This command is in format of: `{compiler} {flags} path/to/file1.o path/to/file2.o path/to/file3.o [...]` and essentially contains all object files created during compilation and in my case is over 34K characters long.

Now historically this has already been looked at, but in my feeling the problem was only raised to a higher character limit. In particular, when looking [here](https://mcuoneclipse.com/2015/03/29/solving-the-8192-character-command-line-limit-on-windows/) it is mentioned there was a problem with 8192 character limit, which seems to be the case when the command was directly passed to command line. The change which attempted to fix it was to use CreateProcess WINAPI function instead, which has a higher limitation of 32767 characters (limits depend on version of Windows used). In case of the project I'm working with, neither limit is high enough, as I've already reached over 34K characters for that particular command.

I've mentioned GNU ARM Elipse as this is what I'm working with, however this is a general issue with the CDT itself and it seems to also be a problem in other IDEs - for example I've read the same kind of reports from Netbeans users. Because I work with embedded systems and there are tools already integrated with Eclipse, moving to another IDE isn't an option.

As for the actual solution - the ideal situation to me would be to have the list of object files passed through a temporary file, as the character limitation is completely bypassed this way. So far I'm using CTD's makefile generator, as it is integrated with the IDE itself (flags, build exclusions etc.), however it isn't configurable in any way or at least none that I'm aware of that would solve my issue.

What are my options here? If it's necessary I might look into the makefile generator itself and modify it to output to file, however I'd rather avoid doing so if it's not the last possible option.

Comment: Hi Jacek, I recently fixed a [similar problem](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=505868)  in CDT for deleting files (project clean). Please [raise a bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=CDT) and we can look at fixing it for CDT, however AFAIK Gnu ARM plug-ins will have to make the same change. Please comment back here with the bug number.

Comment: @JonahGraham Waiting for response from eclipse.org webmaster, they grant Bugzilla permissions by hand now. Will update this thread once I have more information.

Comment: Great, thanks for filing the bug, and persisting through the current Anti-spam mechanism (the spam on bugzilla was overwhelming so this - hopefully temporary - measure was put in place). Let me know if you don't get access in a timely manner too.

Comment: @JonahGraham Bug number: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=508958

Comment: Thanks for the bug report, it is well written and useful.